# django/python variables inside strings?

Tags: python, django, variables, dynamic

I'm new to python and would like some assistance.

I have a variable

```
q = request.GET['q']
```

How do I insert the variable `q` inside this:

```
url = "http://search.com/search?term="+q+"&location=sf"
```

Now I'm not sure what the convention is? I'm used to PHP or javascript, but I'm learning python and how do you insert a variable dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the format method of String:

```
url = "http://search.com/search?term={0}&location=sf".format(q)
```

But of course you should URL-encode the q:

```
import urllib
...
qencoded = urllib.quote_plus(q)
url = 
  "http://search.com/search?term={0}&location=sf".format(qencoded)
```

Comment: I've also seen sometimes using %? Why the difference? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the % approach, but it's the 'old' approach :  `url = "http://...?term=%s&location=s" % (qencoded,)` For a full discussion see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is using `urllib.urlencode()`. It accepts a dictionary(or associative array or whatever you call it) taking key-value pairs as parameter and value and you can encode it to form urls

```
    from urllib import urlencode  
    myurl = "http://somewebsite.com/?"  
    parameter_value_pairs = {"q":"q_value","r":"r_value"}  
    req_url = url +  urlencode(parameter_value_pair)
```

This will give you `"http://somewebsite.com/?q=q_value&r=r_value"`

Answer (score 2):

```
q = request.GET['q']
url = "http://search.com/search?term=%s&location=sf" % (str(q))
```

Use this it will be faster...